# Publish on .NET Core 2.2 SignalR Hub as EXE not working on Self-Host but works in Visual Studio

Tags: .net-core, signalr, self-hosting

I have a Hub that works inside Visual Studio Community 2017 for ASP.Net Core & SignalR. Everything works beautifully as long as it runs under VS. I read what is available & am not getting any luck. I have a HostedService that on StartAsync kicks off a thread with the Background prop set to true. This thread reads from a socket & then calls SendMessage on the Hub. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It publishes an exe, but it is not working.

I have read all that I can find. I added a Hosted Service that is added under Startup.

```
// STARTUP
 public class cRioHubStartup    {       
    
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddHostedService<cRioHubHostService>();            
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        string virtDir = cRioHubGlobals.getHubUrl().VirtualDirectory;
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            //app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<cRioHub>(virtDir);
        });

        app.UseMvc();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("cRioHub Started!");
        });
    }

    /*
        var hubContext = provider.GetService<IHubContext<cRioHub>>();
        services.AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            var hubContext = provider.GetService<IHubContext<cRioHub>>();
            var update = new Update(hubContext);
            return update;
        });
    */

}
```

// HUB HOSTED SERVICE which kicks off background thread

```
public class cRioHubHostService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private static Thread _t = null;

    public Thread thread
    {
        get { return _t; }
    }
            
    // Summary: Triggered when the application host is ready to start the service.
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _t = LaunchHub();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Summary: Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _t = null;
    }

    public static Thread LaunchHub()
    {
        Object orfu = new object(); // saved for fut. use if needed

        // set up hub
        cRioHubConnection hub = new cRioHubConnection(cRioHubGlobals.getHubUrl(), cRioHubGlobals.getHubUrl().Name);
        cRioHubGlobals.setHubConnection(new cRioHubConnection(hub));
        //Globals.HubCnxn.SendMessage("Take2!");
        
        // call thread to start TCP client wh. writes back to the hub on cRio msg. arrival
        Thread t = new Thread(cRioHubTcpClient.cRioRunClient);
        t.IsBackground = true;            
        t.Start(orfu);

        return t;
    }

    public static void cRioRunClient(Object orfu)
    {
        string consMsg = "";

        string urlHub = cRioHubGlobals.getHubUrl().makeUrl();
        string urlCRio = cRioHubGlobals.getCRioUrl().makeUrl();

        string fmtHubUrl    = "Hub URL={0}" ;
        string fmtCRioUrl   = "cRio URL={0}";
         
        consMsg = String.Format(fmtHubUrl, urlHub);
        Console.WriteLine(consMsg);

        consMsg = String.Format(fmtCRioUrl, urlCRio);
        Console.WriteLine(consMsg);

        
        cRioHubGlobals.setCRioTcpClient(new cRioHubTcpClient(orfu)); // gets its connection info from cRioHubGlobals

        cRioHubGlobals.getCRioTcpClient().Message += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine("Client: " + a.Message);

        Task clientTask = cRioHubGlobals.getCRioTcpClient().RunAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Program: Hit any char to stop.");
        ConsoleEx.ReadChar();
        cRioHubGlobals.getCRioTcpClient().Stop = true;
        cRioHubGlobals.getCRioTcpClient().Dispose();
        clientTask = null;
    }

    public static Task cRioStopClient()
    {
        Task tskHub = null;
        cRioHubTcpClient client = cRioHubGlobals.getCRioTcpClient();
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Stop = true;
            client.Dispose();
            tskHub = cRioHubGlobals.getHubConnection().Stop();                       
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping service!");
        return tskHub;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the publisher with the appsettings & launch. If you choose a port other than the default 5000, it is not working. If you choose 5000, it works. This appears to be a bug.